# VLC doesn't display while streaming webcam output to file

Tags: sound, xubuntu, video, vlc, webcam

I'm using [instructions from here](https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-record-webcam-video-using-vlc-media-player/) to record webcam output to mp4 file on my Xubuntu 16.04 machine. It saves the output to file perfectly, but only problem is that I'm unable to view webcam output on the VLC while the recording is being done (even though I've ticked the *Display Locally* check-box). What I'm seeing is just a still image.

For professional quality videos, its important to be able to see yourself for coordination and reflection while recording the video. I'd like to know if something is wrong with my setup or this is a known bug in VLC and whether there is a workaround for this? ([This discussion thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-143732.html) seems to suggest that it could be a problem in VLC).